# How To Center Text in a table that is created using a macro in Word

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a macro that creates a table with 2 columns. I want to center the text.

I need to know the actual function/method to do this (i.e not recorded) as I am editing a complex macro in a specific tool outside of Microsoft Word.

```
Function TableStyleApply(oTable)
  Const wdLineWidth050pt = 4
  Const wdLineStyleSingle = 1
  Const wdBorderTop = -1
  Const wdBorderLeft = -2
  Const wdBorderBottom = -3
  Const wdBorderRight = -4
  Const wdBorderHorizontal = -5
  Const wdBorderVertical = -6
  Const wdAlignParagraphCenter = 100

  oTable.Borders(wdBorderTop ).LineStyle = wdLineStyleSingle
  oTable.Borders(wdBorderLeft ).LineStyle = wdLineStyleSingle
  oTable.Borders(wdBorderBottom ).LineStyle = wdLineStyleSingle
  oTable.Borders(wdBorderRight ).LineStyle = wdLineStyleSingle
  oTable.Borders(wdBorderHorizontal).LineStyle = wdLineStyleSingle
  oTable.Borders(wdBorderVertical).LineStyle = wdLineStyleSingle

  oTable.Rows(1).Range.Font.Bold = True
  oTable.Rows(1).Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = 15132390
  oTable.Rows.LeftIndent = 43
  oTable.Columns(1).SetWidth 280, 2
  oTable.Columns(2).SetWidth 157, 2

  oTable.Columns.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphCenter

End Function
```

Comment: what is the difference if it's recorded or not. MacroRecorder is your first and best solution to get this...property. So, you should use it. However, what you need is possibly something like this: `Selection.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphCenter`

Comment: thanks KazJaw - i did try this but got an error. It states the wdAlignParagraphCenter is not defined. So i tried adding a line that says Const wdAlignParagraphCenter = 1 but still no luck

Comment: you mentioned you use `specific tool outside of microsoft word` which could be a problem... what is that tool? what is your current code?

Comment: Hi Kaz I use a tool called MEGA. I have added the code that styles the table above. all other statements work except the alignment one - the error message says the object doesn't support the function

Comment: is it VBA (programming language)?

Comment: yes MEGA allows you to write scripts to perform functions. in this instance it is creating a table which is then placed into a word document.

Comment: Hi Kaz, Thanks for getting back to me with the answer. However this still is not working for some reason. I guess it is becasue I am using an external program to generate the table. I will keep trying though! :)

Answer (score 4):

You need to refer to any Range object if you want to align your text in center. So, try with this options

**For whole table**

```
oTable.Range.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphCenter
```

**For any single column** (here, for 1st and 2nd columns)

```
oTable.Columns(1).Select
    Selection.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphCenter

oTable.Columns(2).Select
    Selection.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphCenter
```

Comment: Hi Kaz - FYI I managaed to get this working through trial and error by adding   oWordDocument.Range.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = 1 elsewhere in my code.

Comment: why the select? why not `oTable.Columns(1).ParagraphFormat.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphCenter` directly?

Answer (score 0):

This line set alignment to center for all cells in a specific table:

```
cDoc.Tables(1).Range.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphCenter
```